# vb.net not an instance of object won't go away even after casting

Tags: vb.net, object, dictionary

i have the following code which walks through an Excel file and this works fine

Please note that the following line does work well (folder is being set earlier in the code)

```
Console.WriteLine("Value found in {1}: {0} ", Obj.Text, folder)
```

the whole

```
For Each xlWorkSheet In xlWorkBook.Worksheets
    For rCnt As Integer = 2 To xlWorkSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count 'we start at 2 becuase we do not need the first header row

        For cCnt As Integer = 1 To xlWorkSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count

            Dim Obj As Range = CType(xlWorkSheet.UsedRange.Cells(rCnt, cCnt), Range)

            Console.WriteLine("Value found in {1}: {0} ", Obj.Text, folder)

        Next


        RaiseEvent ImportChanged()
    Next

Next
```

But I would like to fill a dictionary with the items, but the moment I do that it complains it "not being an instance of an object" even if I cast  it to Cstr() or use .toString

Anyone knows why?

```
Dim EntryDetails As Dictionary(Of String, String)

        For Each xlWorkSheet In xlWorkBook.Worksheets
            For rCnt As Integer = 2 To xlWorkSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count 'we start at 2 becuase we do not need the first header row

                For cCnt As Integer = 1 To xlWorkSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count

                    Dim Obj As Range = CType(xlWorkSheet.UsedRange.Cells(rCnt, cCnt), Range)

                    Console.WriteLine("Value found in {1}: {0} ", Obj.Text, folder)
                    EntryDetails.Add("demo", Obj.Text) ' THIS DOESNT WORK
                    EntryDetails.Add("demo", Obj.Text.ToString) ' THIS DOESNT WORK
                    EntryDetails.Add("demo", CStr(Obj.Text)) ' THIS DOESNT WORK

                Next


                RaiseEvent ImportChanged()
            Next

        Next
```

Comment: works well, i mean it actually displays the Text value...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't created an actual instance of `EntryDetails`

Add the `New` keyword to the first line so that the constructor is called:

```
Dim EntryDetails As New Dictionary(Of String, String)

For Each xlWorkSheet In xlWorkBook.Worksheets
    // ...
Next
```

Comment: This is a good reason to learn to use the debugger.  You could have easily checked which object was null.